# where is more powerfull, im runing 1 machine for 1 server or 1 machine for multy VM

Tags: apache, webserver, virtualization, vmware, xen

i want to buil a service but im confused whit 2 option

option 1 :
im runing apache, mysql, ftp, in one machine and 1 os (NO VM)

option 2 :
im make each server such as apache, mysql at one Virtual machine.
so apache server have 1 Vm, Mysql server have 1 VM to.

but im only have 1 phisical machine.

where is more powerfull option 1 or 2?

Comment: without more information cannot tell.  Is your service IO bound? CPU bound? memory Bound? In the above it would probably be a wash since you are still throwing the exact same amount of resources at it. but answer depends a lot of what you are running and what your workloads look like.

Answer (score 1):

Probably option 1, since option 2 involves communicting between VMs which is a LOT of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I have another option: 1VM on 1 Physical machines. All application run in this VM.

There is some overhead by virtualization. But AFAI, xen's overhead is quite small. I actually do this on my site http://fclose.com/ which runs on top of old PC with 1G memory. This PC have the webserver on one VM and ssh server on another VM and the domain0 also serves as my desktop for browsing webpage, printing etc. (of course, no big job).

The benefits is easier management and backup. I just shutdown the VM, backup the VM's image or LVM partition and then start the VM again. This can be done automatically by cron with scripts. We only need to deal with one image file or one partition. The job is much smaller although we need more disk space.